# Mutually exclusive selection of Radiobutton in gridView.ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select One">

    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />

    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        RadioButton rad = (RadioButton)di.FindControl("RadioButton1");

        if (rad.Checked&&rad!=null)
        {
            s = di.Cells[1].Text;
        }

    }

    Response.Redirect("applicants.aspx?form=" +s);

}
```

I'm selecting the rows that are selected with this but I have a problem here I want user to be able to select only one `radiobutton` but its allowing all the `radiobutton`s to be selected at once.Can you help me in removing this problem please.
please.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm too late here on the party but this will do the trick,
[check out here......](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-make-single-radio-button.html)

This might be useful for someone watching this answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In the ASP page you need to set the `GroupName` property to be the same for all the radio buttons, e.g.:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="RadioGroup" />
```

Comment: I have only one ID `RadioButton1` which will be created on the fly in every row according to results.

Comment: The GroupName's value is stored in the viewstate, is it possible you have the viewstate disabled?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname.aspx

Answer (score 0):

well for that you can use follwing code
first of all you should define the groupName.The follwing code will work

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" OnCheckedChanged="rbSelector_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="Apply" runat="server"></asp:RadioButton>
```

**C#**

```
protected void rbSelector_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow oldrow in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        ((RadioButton)oldrow.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = false;
    }


    //Set the new selected row
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)rb.NamingContainer;
    ((RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link to select single radiobutton in grid : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/krishnasarala/select-single-radio-button-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

Using the [GroupName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname.aspx) property by itself won't work, each radio button will still get a unique name attribute since they're in different rows of the grid.

One option is to emit the radio button markup manually using a Literal control ([example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-cs)).  This will make it easy to group the radio buttons on the client-side, but requires a bit more work to determine which button was selected on postback.

When I needed this behavior, I found it easier to keep the radio buttons as server-side controls, and just enforce the button group w/ jQuery.  Put your [RadioButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx) in a TemplateField as you've shown, then add this code to uncheck all the other buttons when one is checked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // could also pass in a unique ID selector
    createManualRadioButtonGroupForGridView(".myGridViewClass");
});

function createManualRadioButtonGroupForGridView(gridViewSelector) {
    $(gridViewSelector + " input[type=radio]").change(function () {
        var checkedRadioButton = this;
        $(gridViewSelector + " input[type=radio]").each(function (e) {
            if (this !== checkedRadioButton) {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    });
}
```